# Deleting from a Balanced Binary Search Tree

Tags: c

I want to delete a node, from a Balanced BST. I wrote the following code, and it works on deleting a child, but when I want to delete a node with two childs, a link is restored, but I lose the other node. This is my code:

```
 Nod* minValue(Nod *p)
{
  Nod *q = p;

    while (q->stg != NULL)
       q = q->stg;

   return q;
}

Nod* os_delete(Nod *p, int k) 
{
   if (p == NULL)
       return p;

   if (k < p->ch)
  {
    p->stg = os_delete(p->stg, k);
  }

  else if (k > p->ch)
  {
     p->dr = os_delete(p->dr, k);
  }

  else
  {
      p->size--;
      if (p->stg = NULL)
      {
          Nod* aux = p->dr;
          free(p);
          return aux;
      }
      else if (p->dr == NULL)
      {
          Nod* aux = p->stg;
          free(p);
          return aux;
      } 

      Nod* aux = minValue(p->dr);
      p->ch = aux->ch;
      p->dr = os_delete(p->dr, aux->ch);
  }
  return p;
```

}

For example:

```
          9
    4          15
 1     7    10     18
```

If I want to delete the node with the key 4, the result tree will be:

```
        9
 7            15
           10     18
```

Edit:

```
typedef struct nod
{
   int ch, size; // ch - key of the node; size - size of node's subtree
   struct nod *stg, *dr; // stg - left; dr - right
}Nod;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deletion in binary search tree](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7606185/deletion-in-binary-search-tree)

Comment: s/childs/children/. :-)

Comment: What does the `Nod` structure/class look like?

Comment: I edited the post.

Comment: Can you show what you actually got in addition to what you expected?

Comment: What do you mean "in addition"? I posted an example above.

Answer (score 0):

One way of deleting from a balanced binary tree is to create a function balance(). This will be used to rebalance the tree. Copy the reference pointers of the elements in the binary tree into a list in Inorder. Then find the middle element of the list(dividing the list in two halves). It will be your new root node. Left child of the root node will be the middle of the left half of the list and the right child of the root node will be the middle of the right half of the list. do this recursively to create a balanced tree. 
Now use this function in the deletion process. While finding the node to be deleted, keep track of it's parent. Now build the deletion logic like you would in case of a BST but using this balance() function to rebalance the tree whenever required. 
Source: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/68500/Balanced-Binary-Search-Tree-BST-Search-Delete-InOr

I am not sure how you are trying to keep the tree balanced but another easier way is implementing self-balancing binary search trees like AVL or R-B tree.